# PHP echo background image

Tags: php

I know I'm probably missing something really obvious, but the background image isn't pulling through...

```
<div style='background-image: url(<?php echo $blogImage; ?>");'>
```

I've also tried:

```
<div <?php echo "style='background-image: url($blogImage);'";?> >
```

Comment: have you var_dumped `$blogImage` to make sure it contains the value you're expecting?

Comment: First check should  always be "Count your quotes", make sure they match

Comment: is this issuee solved? i'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax error
Use this

```
<div style="background-image: url('<?php echo $blogImage; ?>');">
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing **`"`** before the **`php opening tag`**. try to add it and check.

```
<div style='background-image: url("<?php echo $blogImage; ?>");'>
```